# Compile error while generalizing function - complex error message

Tags: haskell, ghc

I had a function that runs in IO monad:

```
withDB :: (forall c. IConnection c => c -> IO b) -> IO b
withDB fn = bracket (connectSqlite3 "int/db.sqlite3") disconnect fn
```

And now I decided to generalize it to run in some `MonadIO m`. I did it following way, re-inventing `bracket` with my `scope` (do you know some from library?):

```
scope :: MonadIO m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> (a -> m c) -> m c
scope before after action = do
    x <- before
    r <- action x
    _ <- after x
    return r

withDB :: MonadIO m => (forall c. IConnection c => c -> m b) -> m b
withDB fn = liftIO $ scope
                       (liftIO $ connectSqlite3 "int/db.sqlite3")
                       (\x -> liftIO $ disconnect x) fn
```

I got the error:

```
Could not deduce (m ~ IO)
from the context (MonadIO m)
  bound by the type signature for
    withDB :: MonadIO m => (forall c. IConnection c => c -> m b) -> m b
  at src\...
  'm' is a rigid type variable bound by
    the signature for
      withDB :: MonadIO m => (forall c. IConnection c => c -> m b) -> m b
Expected type: IO b
  Actual type: m b
In the third argument of 'scope' namely 'fn'
In the second argument of '($)', namely
  'scope
    (liftIO $ connectSqlite3 "int/db.sqlite3")
    (\x -> liftIO $ disconnect x)
    fn'
```

And now my questions:

1. What does mean m ~ IO? What first two lines of error say? Also, I saw this ~ construction in haskell code but can't find what is it. Extension? What is rigid type variable?
2. I found error and fixed it. It's enough to remove `liftIO $` before `scope`. But it was just try-recompile cycle. *Where* in this error message told about the place of the error? I see something wrong with 'fn'. OK, I thought about it a bit and have a guess: GHC infers type from top to bottom. And it inferred from using `liftIO` that `m` should be `IO` but `fn` has general type `m` so it is error. Does *any* haskell compiler infers from top to bottom? And (more important) can I see types that GHC infers for sub expressions in output?

Thank you for reading this long question!

Comment: Just FYI your `scope` function does not do exactly what `bracket` does. `bracket` not only wraps a computation into a 'bracket' of resource allocation/release, but also handles exceptions, freeing the resource even in case of exception. Your `scope` function will just exit, not freeing the resource. Maybe this is not critical in this case, but still.

Comment: Does generic MonadIO can handle exception?

Comment: I think that you can manage this with `liftIO`. It has `IO a -> m a` type after all, and all exception handling routines have `IO` types. You can find all exception-related functions here: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.5.0.0/doc/html/Control-Exception.html

Comment: @demi: No, not all `MonadIO`s can handle exceptions (you can't use `catch`, because you'd need to be able to convert from `m a` to `IO a`). If you want to do this, take a look at the [monad-control](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control) and [lifted-base](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lifted-base) packages, specifically `Control.Exception.Lifted`.

Answer (score 4):

`liftIO :: (MonadIO m) => IO a -> m a` takes an `IO` action, so by saying `liftIO $ scope ...`, you're saying that `scope ...` must have the type `IO b`. That means that the arguments to `scope` must use the `IO` monad. Since your use of `scope` ensures that `m` must be `IO`, you can think of `scope` as having this type in context:

```
scope :: IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> (a -> IO c) -> IO b
```

Because of this, the `liftIO`s *inside* the `scope` call do nothing; they're merely converting from `IO a` to `IO a`, and you can't use `fn`, because it works in `m`, not `IO`. Removing the `liftIO` fixed it because it ran `scope` directly inside `m`, rather than running it in `IO` (impossible, because `fn` runs in `m`) and lifting that action into `m`.

Comment: OK, so any type inference goes from outermost expression to inner (i.e. from root of expression tree to leafs, not from leafs to root)? And what m ~ IO means?

Comment: `m ~ IO` means that it's trying to prove that `m` is equal to `IO`, but it isn't (necessarily).

Comment: @demi: It's not necessarily about which direction type inference works in, but about constraints: your use of `liftIO` *requires* that `scope ...` have the type `IO b`. As Louis says, "Could not deduce `(a ~ b)`" means that your code requires `a` and `b` to be the same to work, but they aren't necessarily.